# Installing WSO 2 on premises server replacing the Mule ESB

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

Current situation is to deploy wso2 as we are using Mule now so i am confused i have to install the WSO2EI or API Manager as well. I have already installed the WSO2EI 6.1.1 with NSSM.

Problem is that i am new to WSO2 so just need some steps that how many products i need to install and also on premises.

Answer (score 1):

It Depends upon your requirement, you just cannot install wso2 product without knowing the requirement, WSO2 EI is used for data services and ESB related functionality and API manager is used to expose the API provide security to API using OAUTH2.
So it all depends on your requirement, if you are planning to migrate from mule ESB to wso2 then you need to first make a note of all the functionality you used in mule and how and which products of wso2 you can use to achieve it

Comment: yes i need both to be installed like i will create apis in wso2 esb and then published it and implement the security from api manager. How to do it.. well currently i have installed the wso2 EI and create one api and deploy it and wsoei carbon and its working fine.

Comment: Create API in API manager and then provide ESB endpoint , try following the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+and+Publish+an+API

Comment: but how to install both in one machine as they are two different products.

Comment: You can install on same machine, however you need to change the port for either of them, go to carbon.xml file which is under "\repository\conf" and then change the offset

Comment: see for both we need to set ccarbon_hone variable as environment so i already set for wso2 EI now whow can i set for API Manager. or should i need to extract the API Manager inside the wso EI

Comment: @amg_amit yes in Mule we are using ESB to create API and API Manager to expose the APIs but now in WSO2 how i can install the API Manager as mule the API Manager is cloud based but in wso2 i want on premises.